# Find AID of NFC reader

Tags: android, nfc, emulation, hce, contactless-smartcard

I've made my Android device emulate an NFC card using HCE and `processCommandApdu()`. Now I need to find the Aplication ID(AID) used by the reader of the card. If i'm not mistaken, I need the AID so I can add it to my manifest file in my android app, this way the reader will detect my phone as one of its cards.

The rest of the sectors are all 0's except for the access bits and keys which are the same as in sector 3. I was trying to read on the structure of the card but I haven't been able to find were the AID is stored, if it is at all.

Is it possible to extract the AID from the card dump? If not, is there another way? The card used is a Mifare Classic 1k.

Comment: Since your card is a MIFARE Classic card, it does not use the concept of AIDs in the sense of ISO/IEC 7816-4. Moreover, it uses a proprietary protocol that cannot be emulated using Android HCE. Consequently, what you are trying to do is simply not possible using Android HCE.

Comment: After the edit, the question is also a possible duplicate of [Emulate Mifare card with Android 4.4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20055497/2425802)

Comment: Further information can also be found in [Why doesn't Android HCE support Mifare Classic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27396659/2425802)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.