# How to simulate Mifare Classic 1k card with Android?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, hce

I am trying to understand if [this is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396659/why-doesnt-android-hce-support-mifare-classic-type) to simulate Mifare Classic 1k card with [Android HCE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) or without HCE.

This [NFC Card Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yuanwofei.cardemulator) app [is able](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409934/editing-functionality-of-host-card-emulation-in-android/28720342#28720342) to simulate card and its ID (not data).
NFC Tools Pro is able to simulate NFC tag data. Not sure if NFC Card Emulator and NFC Tools Pro together are able to simulate the Mifare card.

Here is the sample card I would like to start with - pastebin.com/DUXY0Bcx.