# Mifare Card Emulation on Android 10?

Tags: android, emulation, nfc, mifare

After researching about Mifare (Classic) card emulation on Android devices I've found information that says that it's not possible on older Android versions (e.g. [Why doesn't Android HCE support Mifare Classic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396659/why-doesnt-android-hce-support-mifare-classic-type) or [Emulate Mifare card with Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055497/emulate-mifare-card-with-android-4-4)). Is this still the case on Android 10? If so, is it a hardware thing? (maybe phones are not able to emulate them).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't think anything has changed in the links provided. You can also check the [Android Compatibility Definition Document section on NFC](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd#7_4_4_near-field_communications) to see what is considered supported.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't allow to access the "Secure Element" (chip) using MiFare Classic cards. So it doesn't allow to emulate MiFare classic

Answer (score 2):

With Host Card emulation you are emulating a Type 4 card, Mifare Classic is a Type 2 card (There are also various of standard numbers that relate to these card types mentioned in the links you gave.)

The only thing that has changed on Android 10 relating to NFC is the deprecation of Android Beam (Peer to Peer) NFC.