# Is it possible to emulate Mifare Classic 1k with android NFC

Tags: android, emulation, nfc, mifare

Most of the stackoverflow topics said the opposite but I found [this](https://www.mifare.net/support/forum/topic/simulate-mifare-classic-1k-with-android-nfc/) saying otherwise. Is it possible ?

Comment: Well, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055497/emulate-mifare-card-with-android-4-4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396659/why-doesnt-android-hce-support-mifare-classic-type) answer says that it's not possible, and provide some details as to why that is. The forum post you linked to appears to be related to some technology called mifare4mobile, which seems like a lower-level feature not available to ordinary app developers.

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael says not possible for normal developers, if you are building your own phone hardware and rom you can could choose a NFC chip that supported and had this in it's secure element.

Most phones do have a secure elements as this is used to support Wallet type functionality where your credit card details are kept isolated from the OS.

There are some chips on dev boards and in USB readers that support Mifare emulation in hardware.