# How to clone a MIFARE classic 1K card on an Android phone

Tags: mifare, nxp-microcontroller

I'm working on a project which purpose is to emulate the classic 1k card on a smartphone (with an NFC chip) via website (eg django) or an android application in order to access university buildings without the badge but only with the phone.

I'm looking for some information on internet and I discovered that there are M4M api (TapLinx SDK) but I'm not sure if it works for my job.
The question is: M4M api are ok for my aim? If so, it's better to develop a website or an android app? do you have any suggestion about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Android HCE support Mifare Classic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396659/why-doesnt-android-hce-support-mifare-classic-type)